# eroding several layers of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm having trouble understanding scipy's `binary_erosion` function.

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion
a = np.zeros([12,12])
a[1:11,1:11]=1
binary_erosion(a).astype(int)
```

this removes the outermost edges, but what if I want to remove the second layer as well? I know I should probably use the `structure` option, but I don't understand how it works and could not find enough examples that explain it properly

Comment: Erosion is a common, yet simple morphological operation in image processing. If you want to understand more about it, I recommend this read https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

Comment: Thanks @yellow01, very useful link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `iterations` option to have it repeat `n` times (remove additional layers): [[source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html)]

> iterations : *int*, optional
>   The erosion is repeated iterations times (one, by default). If iterations is less than 1, the erosion is repeated until the result does not change anymore.

So yours:

```py
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And with the iterations option set to 2, you'll notice an additional layer has been reduced.

```py
>>> binary_erosion(a, iterations=2).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

Since you asked in a comment, the `structure` can be used to determine how much to remove for each `iteration`. There is a good breakdown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)#Example) of what that means.

This is `the structuring element used for erosion`. Meaning that if this were a 3x3 square, as it moved around the edge, the pixels that are completely covered will get removed, and the ones that are only partially covered will stay.

Also take a look at [this medium post](https://medium.com/@aguigui17/activity-8-morphological-operations-in-progress-c86cf3fe64d) which has hand drawn a bunch of examples for how this works and breaks it down even further.

Comment: thanks, it works great! I was looking at the wrong option... what does the `structure` option do then?

Comment: @HappyPy I have added some at the bottom with some good links to walk through what exactly that means. Highly recommend the second one as it has a lot of examples in the first half of the post.